# Android Wear - Vector Drawable not visible on real device

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os, android-vectordrawable

I implemented a couple of extended notification for android wear, extended in order to show action like this:

```
//Notification builder&other code...
.addAction(new Notification.Action.Builder(R.drawable.ic_phone_android_32dp,
                                    "Open on phone", serviceOpenpendingIntent)
                                    .build())
//Show notification & bla bla...
```

I'm trying to use the following drawable (**ic_insert_photo_24dp.xml**), imported in Android Studio using the "add vector drawable" functionality:

```
 <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:pathData="M21,19V5c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2H5c-1.1,0 -2,0.9 -2,2v14c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2h14c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2zM8.5,13.5l2.5,3.01L14.5,12l4.5,6H5l3.5,-4.5z"/>
```

The Drawable is working perfectly on handheld, and works fine on wear emulator, too, with results similar to this:

[image]

Anyway, **when I test on a real device (Moto 360) I can only see the blue circle, without the icon**. If I use "old-style" drawable (say .png) everything works as expected. **Can you tell why**?

**UPDATE**: guys at Google say this is an OEM [specific issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=189614&thanks=189614&ts=1444646823)

**UPDATE2**: guys at Google accepted the issue: Labels: Component-Wear Defect-27725751

Comment: Can you prepare a full sample that demonstrates the behavior, and put it on github or somewhere so I can test it out myself? If I can reproduce it, I will file a bug for you.

Comment: I've been running into the same issue on Moto 360 v2. Did you happen to find any sort of workaround, e.g. using a specific icon color/transparency etc. in the vector drawable?